Can I use petroleum based penetrating oil/lubricant on copper/brass pipe fixtures?
I have a threaded copper and/or brass pipe fixture that is giving me trouble when unscrewing. I'd like to try spraying the threads with penetrating oil/lubricant to assist. I have a good oil/lubricant I've used on car parts, but wanted to double check if there's any special chemical concerns (or potable water concerns) I need to be aware of for copper or brass. This spray proclaims to be a petroleum based penetrating oil and lubricant: is that okay to use?

More of potable water concerns.  If it can be done safety, heating the outside fitting and placing an ice bag on the inside pipe might help.  Pictures of the fitting might help.

Whether it is ok or not would be dependant on the specifics of your situation.   Is this something that is screwed on and off often or a one time need for a repair?

It's a 1 time repair

heat is usually efficient in that case. But if you do use the oil, flush the line after the repair is complete.

I assume you know, but plumbing always requires two wrenches to tighten/loosen stuff.

In addition to applying heat, gentle tapping with a small hammer while trying to loosen should break up corrosion sealing that joint.
BTW, be careful -- old brass (and copper, to a lesser extent) may become brittle with use. It might be safer to cut the pipe right at the fitting, and solder on a new one, lest toque break the pipe inside a wall.
